# Better way to do what I need to do using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

I'm not sure if there is a more efficient way of doing what I'm doing using LINQ... I have two enumerations:

enumA(string): `{ "Andy", "Bill", "Charlie", "Doug" }`
enumB(foo): `{ "Doug", "Edward", "George", "Bill" }` (Note that enumB actually contains objects)

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, 
foreach (var a in enumA)
{
    var b = enumB.SingleOrDefault(x => String.Equals(x.ToString(), a));

    if (b != null)
        dictionary[a] = b;
}
```

---

It just seems bad to me to enumerate over enumB over and over again and create a dictionary this way when I'm sure there is probably a more "correct" way to create a dictionary using LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it efficiently using a

```
join
```

and an

```
ToDictionairy
```

call afterwards.

```
        var listA = "abcd";
        var listB = "cdef";

        var tuples = from charFromA in listA
                    join charFromB in listB
                    on charFromA.ToString() equals charFromB.ToString() // instead of ToString(), do something complex
                    select new { A = charFromA, B = charFromB };

        var dictionairy = tuples.ToDictionary(keySelector: t => t.A,elementSelector: t => t.B);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from b in enumB.Where(x => x != null)
            join a in enumA on b.ToString() equals a
            select new { a, b };
var dictionary = query.ToDictionary(x => x.a, x => x.b);
```

Or with fluent API:

```
var dictionary = enumB.Where(b => b != null)
                      .Join(enumA, 
                            b => b.ToString(), 
                            a => a, 
                            (b, a) => new { a, b })
                      .ToDictionary(x => x.a, x => x.b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dictionary = enumA
    .Join(enumB, a => a, b => b.ToString(), (a, b) => new { A = a, B = b })
    .ToDictionary(i => i.A, i => i.B);
```

This will throw an exception if there are any duplicate keys, so you can use:

```
var dictionary = enumA
    .Join(enumB, a => a, b => b.ToString(), (a, b) => new { A = a, B = b })
    .Aggregate(new Dictionary<string, Foo>(), (dict, i) => {
        dict[i.A] = i.B;
        return dict;
    });
```

which will keep the last matching value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dict = enumA.Join(enumB, a => a, b => b, (a, b) => new {a, b})
                .GroupBy(x => x.a)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First());
```

GroupBy is to eliminate possible duplicates in enumB.

if enumB duplicates don't exist you can simplify it to

```
var dict = enumA.Join(enumB, a => a, b => b, (a, b) => new {a, b})
                .ToDictionary(x => x.a, x => x.b);
```